# Excel VBA - Turn Off Notify Or Read Only option on File Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook with macros that is available to several people in different locations(towns) on a corporate intranet. When one person opens it with read/write access we don't want other people to have the option "Notify when available" or Read Only Access. This is to avoid the situation where people save files on their desktop and afterwards someone will have to update the master file.

How do I make it so if person A has the document open while person B tries to open it, they get a message saying try again later?  I tried the code below but it did not work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim blnReadonly As Boolean

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

blnReadonly = ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly

If blnReadonly = True Then
    MsgBox ("Application may not open in read only mode, try again later")
    Application.Quit
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What error message are you getting when you run the code?

Comment: The `blnReadonly` variable is not needed, and the `bool = True` check also - just do `If ThisWorkbook.Readonly Then ...`.

Comment: I would change additionally from `Application.Quit` to `ThisWorkbook.Close` to keep other workbooks currently opened by the user on his computer. If not all will be closed without any possibility to save them before close.

Comment: This is not a job for a vba  macro,  you should use cvs  our any other version management software

Comment: The issue is that Excel's message runs first (on screen ) before the Macro: {Private Sub Workbook_Open()}  runs. That is excels ReadOnly, Notify , Cancel message preceeds the VBA message.